# Asked a question; actual answer was combination of two answers with some extra info

Tags: discussion

I asked a question. Two people answered, and each provided half of the correct answer with a tiny bit that was missing. I have no idea how best to select the "correct" answer.

I am totally new to Blender.

The question in question is [Move vertices parallel with face they define](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282307/move-vertices-parallel-with-face-they-define).

Thanks!

Comment: ... a very comprehensive answer from @Duarte . In this case, I would approve the solution you found most practical, and  actually used :)

Comment: Thank you @RobinBetts for your answer there and comment here. As best as I can tell, it's split down the middle in terms of actual used-ness, and I got myself confused by the other answer through some light EBKACing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accepting an answer is not mandatory, though it is encouraged.

See [help about what you should do if someone answers your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

> [To accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work):
>
> - Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
> - To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
> - You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.
>
> Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept
> the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that
> answers your question well.

Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

In short the accepted answer should ideally be the one that fully covers your issue, barring that, the one most closely addresses your question.

If non really answer in a satisfying manner you may also:

1. Answer your own question with the solution you found or compiled from other answers. After a grace period of 48h, you may choose your own answer as the accepted one. Be sure to write something that distinguishes itself enough from existing answers to justify its existence.
2. Alternatively, you can also comment on any answers of your choice, or that helped you the most, and encourage the users to include those missing details that really made the difference for you.
3. Stack exchange also encourages you to edit any posts you find to make them more useful. With that in mind, you may also edit any answer you found useful and add any missing steps you discovered by yourself.

Both last two options would be preferred, since they allow you you to accept an exist answer, awarding the authors the deserved additional reputation they worked for.

Comment: Thank you. I've accepted this answer :)

Comment: Thanks, made a few changes to make it a bit clearer